# send data to laravel's controller with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, frameworks

I am just trying to send a POST request to my laravel's controller with ajax.. it's perfectly working for 1st time eg. if I fill correct user's information then it redirected to my defined route but if i fill wrong info then i get the error message which i define ,, now the main part is after fill wrong info and message (wrong username and password) appears .then i  retry with correct info but nothing happens i dont know why.. please help me ,, my ajax code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function login(){
      var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
      var link = 'http://localhost/tute/ajax_laravel/public/';
      var values = {email : $("#email").val() , password : $("#password").val() , _token: CSRF_TOKEN};

      $.ajaxSetup({
          header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
      })
      $.ajax({
          url     : link+'login',
          type    : 'POST',
          data    : values,
          success : function(data){
              if (data == 'false'){
                  $('.error').show();
              }
          }
      });
  }
  $('.btn-success').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      login();
  });
```

});

My HTML code is

```
            <div class="hpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                    <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="example@gmail.com" title="Please enter you email"
                     required="" value="" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
                    <span class="help-block small">Your unique Email to app</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" title="Please enter your password" placeholder="******"
                     required="" value="" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                    <span class="help-block small">Your strong password</span>
                </div>
                <div class="error" style="display:none">
                    <p style="color:red">Wrong Email or Password</p>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
                <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" href="#">Register</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Add relevant hml code please

Comment: Not sure why did you put function login() in document.ready()?

Comment: it's just for demo purpose .. forget about it @DEV. :)

Comment: @sandeep Have you checked if function login is called when you try to login 2nd time after incorrect credentials?

Comment: yes sir @Dev , my code is perfectly working with 1st correct info ,, it just not working with the 2nd attempt after fill the wrong Details

Comment: Not about first correct info, but try putting console.log() or javascript alert inside the login function and check it is called each and every time (whether it is correct credentials or incorrect or 3rd time) when you press the button "success"?

Comment: yes sir , i just " alert " into my login function and it working .

Comment: OK. What response did you get after ajax request?

Comment: nothing happens sir. even dint not show any exception error or console error , it just display login page

Comment: In that case you need to put dd() statement inside your controller method which is being called by the ajax request and need to see what is happening there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is problem with `CSRF` token. If you really want to do login with `ajax` you can disable `CSRF` validation by comment `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` from `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`

```
protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
];
```

Either you can get new generated token by create a new function of javascript in your `login.blade.php`

```
<script>
    function newToken(){
        return '{{csrf_token()}}';
    }
</script>
```

call this function in your jquery file to attach new generated token with your ajax request.